# I have Installed the Titanium studio.Ink In Windows from appcelerator website but unable to run app like Kitchen sink?

Tags: titanium

I have also tried to install Android sdk & updates but its end up showing that java jdk not installed as I have Installed the JDK earlier

and In the Console Part-->

Titanium Command-Line Interface,CLI version 3.1.1,Titanium SDK version 3.1.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013,Appcelerator,Inc. All Rights Reserved.

[ERROR]  : "Missing Java SDK.Please make sure Java SDK is on your PATH

What To DO !!

Comment: The message is rather clear: "make sure Java SDK is on your PATH". Check you PATH environmental variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method to set environmental variables and plz make sure that you are using javasdk 1.6 instead of 1.7

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check whether java is in your path. If not install JDK and JRE and try once again